# Deleting rows from a table using a loop

Tags: ms-access, vba, loops, recordset

Why does my `Do Until` loop try to run `raw.Delete` even though `raw.EOF` is true? If I have an empty table, this crashes. Why?

```
Dim raw As Recordset
Set raw = db.OpenRecordset("tblSampleRaw")

If raw.RecordCount > 0 Then
    raw.MoveFirst

    Do Until raw.EOF
        raw.MoveFirst
        raw.Delete
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, or a VBA expert,  but how come you are constantly doing a MoveFirst?  Your never moving forward in the recordset.  Try

```
Do Until raw.EOF
        raw.Delete
        raw.MoveNext
 Loop
```

Comment: Move to first record, delete it, then what is first? The next record I would hope

Comment: Well if that was true you would never need to do a MoveFirst then would you?  You do it initially outside your loop so you should always be on the first record.

Comment: Also I don't think you hit EOF until you move passed the last record.

Comment: you just took the words out of my mouth! +1

Comment: The deleted record is not removed from the recordset unless you requery it. You can see this in a continuous or datasheet form in Access if you elsewhere delete a record displaying in the form the record selector and all the controls for that record will remain in the form, but with #DELETED in all the controls.

Comment: ...but I think this is crazy code to begin with. In the form it's posted, it is completely unjustifiable.

Comment: You mean the code to loop through the RS and delete rows?  Yes I agree but I think the OP was just looking for an explanation as to why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a Row-By-Agonizing-Row or RBAR (reebar) operation. The larger the table, the more time this is going to take.

Most databases can work more efficiently than RBARs. I suggest you think in terms of SETS rather than rows.

I think you should replace that entire block of code with this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblSampleRaw"
```

for purposes of the answer

```
Dim raw As Recordset
Set raw = db.OpenRecordset("tblSampleRaw")

If raw.RecordCount > 0 Then
    raw.MoveFirst

    WHILE NOT raw.EOF or raw.BOF
        raw.MoveFirst
        raw.Delete
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: You are probably right. But a TRUNCATE would even be quicker. I'm just curious why this loop doesn't work though.

Comment: If you're using Jet/ACE, it processes "DELETE * FROM table" as TRUNCATE.

Comment: I think that inside the loop .MoveFirst should be .MoveNext and should be after the Delete.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: What is the * in "DELETE * FROM Table" supposed to do. Delete all columns as opposed to... what?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VB programmer, but it looks like 'raw' is going to keep dropping through the loop even after it executes 'MoveFirst'.

Answer (score 0):

How about Dim raw AS DAO.Recordset?